# Using category attribute of a cfindex tag

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfindex

I'm trying to index a database table using a `<cfindex>`. I also want to categorize the index based on the values of a column of the same table. No documentation I have come across clearly mention what the "category" attribute takes. Is it a column name or just any desire value and if the later then how do the index determine which record belongs to what category?

Thanks a lot in Advance.

```
| ID | CATEGORY |  NAME  |     DETAILS     |    DATE    |
| 1  | people   |  John  |  John details   | 01/23/1980 |
| 2  | animal   |  Dog   |  dogs details   | 02/22/1990 |
| 3  | people   |  Ben   |  Ben's details  | 10/10/2006 |
| 4  | animal   |  panda | panda's details | 07/17/2009 |
```

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion? Are you sure you're using Verity and not Solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs didn't make it clear, but if you are indexing a database and there is a column that you want to use for the category, just pass the name of the db column to the category attribute.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. With the categoryTree attribute; do I just list the categories? I'm new to posting item here even though I use the site a lot so please bare with me.

Comment: Category Tree acts like a hierarchy. While it can be complex, it can also be just one more value. So for example, 2 documents can have a category of football, with the tree value being American vs European.